# Create a matrix of tf-idf values

Tags: python, r, matrix, tf-idf

I have a set of `documents` like:

```
D1 = "The sky is blue."
D2 = "The sun is bright."
D3 = "The sun in the sky is bright."
```

and a set of `words` like:

```
"sky","land","sea","water","sun","moon"
```

I want to create a matrix like this:

```
   x        D1           D2         D3
sky         tf-idf       0          tf-idf
land        0            0          0
sea         0            0          0
water       0            0          0
sun         0            tf-idf     tf-idf
moon        0            0          0
```

Something like the example table given here: http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/spring14/compsci290/assignments/lab02.html. In the given link, it uses the same words from the document but I need to use the set of `words` that I have mentioned.

If the particular word is present in the document then I put the `tf-idf` values, else I put a `0` in the matrix.

Any idea how I might build some sort of matrix like this? Python will be best but R also appreciated.

I am using the following code but am not sure whether I am doing the right thing or not. My code is:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords


train_set = "The sky is blue.", "The sun is bright.", "The sun in the sky is bright." #Documents
test_set = ["sky","land","sea","water","sun","moon"] #Query
stopWords = stopwords.words('english')

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words = stopWords)
#print vectorizer
transformer = TfidfTransformer()
#print transformer

trainVectorizerArray = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_set).toarray()
testVectorizerArray = vectorizer.transform(test_set).toarray()
#print 'Fit Vectorizer to train set', trainVectorizerArray
#print 'Transform Vectorizer to test set', testVectorizerArray

transformer.fit(trainVectorizerArray)
#print
#print transformer.transform(trainVectorizerArray).toarray()

transformer.fit(testVectorizerArray)
#print 
tfidf = transformer.transform(testVectorizerArray)
print tfidf.todense()
```

I am getting very absurd results like this (values are only `0` and `1` while I am expecting values between 0 and 1).

```
[[ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

I am also open to other libraries for calculating `tf-idf`. I just want a correct matrix which I mentioned above.

Comment: Is the output correct? If I do it, I only get three columns and only two entries being 1.

Comment: Is this what you expected: [[ 0.79596054  0.          0.60534851  0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.70710678  0.          0.70710678]
 [ 0.          0.57735027  0.57735027  0.57735027]]

Comment: @andi Yes, the output is correct. I re-checked. I am getting the same output.

Comment: I expect an output like the matrix that I have shown.

Answer (score 2):

A R solution could look like this:

```
library(tm)
docs <- c(D1 = "The sky is blue.",
          D2 = "The sun is bright.",
          D3 = "The sun in the sky is bright.")
dict <- c("sky","land","sea","water","sun","moon")
mat <- TermDocumentMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(docs)), 
                          control=list(weighting =  weightTfIdf, 
                                       dictionary = dict))
as.matrix(mat)[dict, ]
#         Docs
# Terms          D1        D2        D3
#   sky   0.5849625 0.0000000 0.2924813
#   land  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
#   sea   0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
#   water 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
#   sun   0.0000000 0.5849625 0.2924813
#   moon  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

Comment: I am wondering why your method and the another answer in `python` gives me different results. Even if I am using `stopwords` here.

Comment: Perhaps due to `normalization = TRUE` (see `?weightTdIdf` or [here](http://www.inside-r.org/node/96357) )?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stopWords, vocabulary=test_set)
matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_set)
```

(As I said earlier, this is not a test set, this is a vocabulary.)

Comment: I am wondering why your method and the another answer in `R` gives me different results. Even if I am using `stopwords` in `R`.

Comment: @user2481422 The tf-idf in scikit-learn is not the textbook tf-idf. It's actually tf + tf-idf and some more tricks to make it work well in machine learning settings (esp. clustering).

Comment: Then what about that of in R? Do you know the trick to make it work in machine learning?

Comment: @user2481422 I don't do R.

Comment: Do you know the trick to make it work in machine learning? I am asking this because I want the actual `tf-idf` value mentioned in book.

Comment: You could subtract the tf matrix.

Comment: Which is the `tf` matrix in this case?

Comment: What comes out of `CountVectorizer`.

Comment: If I do `t1 = transformer.fit_transform(train_set).todense()
t2 = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_set).todense()
sub = t1 - t2
print sub` - I get negative values which is obviously not correct.